# Sed - substitute only within the line containing braces

Tags: sed

I have been struggling with this all day.  Trying to make variables in sections of a line only contained within braces.
Lines look like this:

```
blah blah [ae b c]  blah [zv y] blah
```

I need to make this:

```
blah blah [$ae $b $c] blah [$zv $y] blah
```

There must be an easy way to do this.  However, whenever I try

```
$ echo "blah blah [ae b c]  blah [zv y] blah" | sed 's/\[\(\b.*\b\)\]/$\1/g'
```

I get greedy matching and just one variable:

```
blah blah $ae b c]  blah [zv y blah
```

Is there something better?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "blah blah [ae b c]  blah [zv y] blah" | sed -r ':b; s/([[][^]$]* )([[:alnum:]]+)/\1$\2/g; t b; s/[[]([[:alnum:]])/[$\1/g'
blah blah [$ae $b $c]  blah [$zv $y] blah
```

#### How it works

- `-r`

  This turns on extended regex.
- `:b`

  This creates a label `b`.
- `s/([[][^]$]* )([[:alnum:]]+)/\1$\2/g`

  This looks for `[`, followed by anything except `]` or `$`, followed by a space, followed by any alphanumeric characters.  It puts a `$` in front of the alphanumeric characters.

  Note that awk convention that makes `[[]` match `[` while `[^]$]` matches anything except `]` and `$`.  This is more portable than attempting to escape these characters with backslashes.
- `t b`

  If the command above resulted in a substitution, this branches back to label `b` so that the substitution is attempted again.
- `s/[[]([[:alnum:]])/[$\1/g`

  The last step is to look for `[` followed by an alphanumeric character and put a `$` between them.

Because `[[:alnum:]]` is used, this code is unicode-safe.

#### Mac OSX (BSD) Version

On BSD sed (OSX) limits the ability to combine statements with semicolons.  Try this instead:

```
sed -E -e ':b' -e 's/([[][^]$]* )([[:alnum:]]+)/\1$\2/g' -e 't b' -e 's/[[]([[:alnum:]])/[$\1/g'
```

Comment: @jstevenco Thanks! I added a version which I think might work on BSD.  (If I had access to a BSD system, I would test it but I don't.)

Comment: Cool; works a treat with one minor mod; the "-r" decorator is actually "-E" [at least] in OSX.

Comment: @jstevenco Thanks again.  Answer corrected: `-r --> `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

To disable it being greedy, instead of matching any character, match any character except closing bracket:

```
sed 's/\[\(\b[^]]*\b\)\]/$\1/g'
```

The task you want to do cannot be done with sed because context-sensitive matching cannot be described with regular grammar.

Comment: It does not work for me. It only replaces the first one and it leaves square brackets out.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to solve it using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). As alternative, you can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) with the help of the `Text::Balanced` module, that extracts text between balanced delimiters, like square brackets. Each call returns an array with the content between delimiters, the text before them and the text after them, so you can apply the regex that insert `$` sign to the significative part of the string.

```
perl -MText::Balanced=extract_bracketed -lne '
    BEGIN { $result = q||; }
    do {
        @result = extract_bracketed($_, q{[]}, q{[^[]*});
        if (! defined $result[0]) {
            $result .= $result[1];
            last;
        }
        $result[0] =~ s/(\[|\s+)/$1\$/g;
        $result .= $result[2] . $result[0];
        $_ = $result[1];
    } while (1);
    END { printf qq|%s\n|, $result; }

' infile
```

It yields:

```
blah blah [$ae $b $c]  blah [$zv $y] blah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\[\([^]]*\)\]/[ \1]/g
:loop
s/\(\(\[[^]$]*\)\([[:blank:]]\)\)\([^][:blank:]$][^]]*\]\)/\1\$\4/g
t loop
s/\[ \([^]]*\)\]/[\1]/g' YourFile
```

- posix version
- assuming there is no bracket inside bracket like `[a b[c] d ]`
- algo:

  - add a space char after opening bracket (needed to use *blank* as starting word separator an often no space for first one)
  - label anchor for a loop
  - add a `$` in front of last word between bracket that does not have one (not starting by `$`). Do it for each bracket group in line, but 1 add per group only
  - if occuring, retry another time going to label loop
  - remove the first space added in first operation

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'h;s/\</$/g;T;G;s/^/\n/;:a;s/\n[^[]*(\[[^]]*\])(.*\n)([^[]*)[^]]*\]/\3\1\n\2/;ta;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line. Insert `$` infront of all start-of-word boundaries. If nothing is substituted print the current line and bale out. Otherwise append the copy of the unadulterated line and insert a newline at the start of the adulterated current line. Using substitution and pattern matching replace the parts of the line between `[...]` with the original matching parts using the newline to move the match forwards through the line. When all matches have been made replace the end of the original line and remove the newlines.